# Minimum solder mask sliver

Tags: altium, solder-mask

I am new to PCB design, and especially on Altium. I am trying out it and have no clue of the best way to fix the following error:

I am trying to build a PCB for a Li-Ion charging circuit based on BQ24072. I have downloaded the symbol, footprint and 3D model from Texas Instrument's website. My manufacturer says they need a minimum of 0.08mm clearance between 2 pads mask. Here is the snapshot of 2D and 3D view of my PCB. What is the best way to overcome this issue?

[image: 2D View]

[image: 3D View]

Comment: Either reduce the solder mask openings, provided that they will comply with your manufacturer's specs, or increase them. In the latter case, you'll lose the benefit of having the solder mask between pins.

Comment: Hi @next-hack, thank you for the answer, but as I said, I am kid on this. So please bear my non-sense questions. So shall I edit the footprint (pcblib doc) that I have downloaded from the vendor (TI)? If you can kindly guide to to another tutorial for the same or any video.

Comment: Yes, you can edit the footprint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is change the soldermask expansion around the pads. You can open up the footprint in the library editor, select the pads, and in the Inspector change the expansion. Generally an expansion of 0.002 inches (0.051 millimeters) is sufficient, but if you have space you could increase that a bit. The required distance between soldermask openings will depend on your board supplier and their requirements.